# Q# Callable Not Accessible from Open Namespace

Tags: programming, q#

I am trying to to call `ApplyMultiplyControlledAnd()`, and I'm receiving an error saying "The callable ApplyMultiplyControlledAnd exists in an open namespace, but is not accessible from here." I have opened Microsoft.Quantum.Canon already, but I'm still getting the error. Any advice as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code of ApplyMultiplyControlledAnd](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/blob/c4f69418a55f3c93f1725a7b090523af28d08885/Standard/src/Canon/And.qs),  it is defined as `internal`, so it's only available to the libraries code, not to the user code.

The non-internal version of this operation seems to be controlled variant of [ApplyAnd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.canon.applyand) or [ApplyLowDepthAnd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.canon.applylowdepthand).